# Visual Studio renders a control in ASP.NET that does not exist anymore

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, iis-express

I'm developing an ASP.NET WebForms application, and until this day, it never gave me problems. But today I found something strange and didn't find any solution for it. I have this code:

```
<a id="goToProductDetailed" runat="server" href="ProductDetailed.aspx" onclick="SetCurrentUrl();">
    <div class="img2">
        <img src='images/test.png'/>
        <div class="promo">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPromo" runat="server" Text='Test' />
        </div>
        <div class="promoImage" id="divFotoRegalo" runat="server" visible="false">
            <a title="Check Product in sale" id="goToProductSale" runat="server" target="_blank">
                <img id="imgFotoRegalo" runat="server">
             </a>
         </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

This represents a basic product card, and when the user clicks on it, it goes to another page. Today, just to see how it would look to make a differente approach, I've put the anchor inside the div class img2, and surrounded just the image with it. I didn't like it, so I've put it back outside the div. But now everytime I open the IIS Express server on Visual Studio it renders two times the anchor, one time outside, and the other time inside the div class img2 surrounding the image.

I've tried to open the IIS Express on Firefox and it does the same, so I don't think it's a cookie problem. But, just to make sure, I've tried to delete them on Chrome and Firefox and didn't work. I've tried to clean project, rebuild it, and didn't work. I've also closed Visual Studio, reopened it, and still didn't work. I don't know what I've done wrong or how can I possibly solve this problem, can someone help me please?

Comment: Have you tried stopping and restarting the IIS Express web server?

Comment: Yes sir, I've tried it and it just keeps giving me the same output. If I change the anchor's position to other position, the "second one" disappears, but in the position I want, meaning in the outside of the div class img2, it automatically generates a twin, even with the same id, which does not even make any sense

Comment: UPDATE: It somehow saved the state of the page, so when I change something it gets normal, but when I put the code exactly like I want, It bugs. If I comment the promoImage div anchor, the first one, that englobes everything, does not bug anymore...

Comment: Your first anchor is invalid, as anchors cannot contain div elements, or if you they do, then they can't contain other interactive elements. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828032/1543677  You will get into all sorts of trouble with invalid HTML. That's why when you remove the offending anchor, it does not "bug".

Comment: Well, techniocally it may be true, but it works just fine and never gave me problems, so I don't understand why is it invalid. Also, it is now working, I restarted the computer and it just got back to normal. But I would like to know, if an anchor is invalid for a card to be clicked, what am I supposed to do to then go to a certain page when I click my card?